# Получение ip клиента сайта Opera

Tags: php

Есть следующий код определяющий ip клиента.

```
$kernelVars['userIp'] = (!empty($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REMOTE_ADDR'])) ? $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REMOTE_ADDR'] : ((!empty($HTTP_ENV_VARS['REMOTE_ADDR'])) ? $HTTP_ENV_VARS['REMOTE_ADDR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Однако в Опере и мобильном Хроме выходит пустое значение.

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В опере возможно через браузерный прокси работает (не 100% информация).
Через мобильные браузеры точно через прозрачные прокси работает интернет.
И получается что одного заголовка для определения ip очень мало. Как минимум есть еще и `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. По поводу определения ip адреса клиента могу порекомендовать вам статью на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/177113/), которая лично мне очень помогла разобраться в происходящем.